# How to load udf jars in flink program

Tags: sql, jar, apache-flink, user-defined-functions

We are using per-job to load udf jar when start job. Our jar file is in another path but not flink's lib path. In the main function, we use classLoader to load the jar file by the jar path. But it reports the following error when job starts running.
      If the jar file is in lib, everything is ok. But our udf jar file is managed in a special path. How can I load udf jars in flink program with only giving the jar path?

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Table program cannot be compiled. This is a bug. Please file an issue.
at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.Compiler$class.compile(Compiler.scala:36)
at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.CRowProcessRunner.compile(CRowProcessRunner.scala:35)
at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.CRowProcessRunner.open(CRowProcessRunner.scala:49)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.open(ProcessOperator.java:56)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:424)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:290)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:723)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: Line 5, Column 1: Cannot determine simple type name "com"
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:11877)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6758)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6519)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6532)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6532)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6532)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6532)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getType2(UnitCompiler.java:6498)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$14000(UnitCompiler.java:218)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$1.visitReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6405)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$1.visitReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6400)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$ReferenceType.accept(Java.java:3983)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22.visitType(UnitCompiler.java:6400)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22.visitType(UnitCompiler.java:6393)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$ReferenceType.accept(Java.java:3982)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getType(UnitCompiler.java:6393)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$1300(UnitCompiler.java:218)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$25.getType(UnitCompiler.java:8206)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getType2(UnitCompiler.java:6798)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$14500(UnitCompiler.java:218)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$2$1.visitFieldAccess(UnitCompiler.java:6423)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$2$1.visitFieldAccess(UnitCompiler.java:6418)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$FieldAccess.accept(Java.java:4365)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$2.visitLvalue(UnitCompiler.java:6418)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$2.visitLvalue(UnitCompiler.java:6414)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Lvalue.accept(Java.java:4203)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22.visitRvalue(UnitCompiler.java:6414)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22.visitRvalue(UnitCompiler.java:6393)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Rvalue.accept(Java.java:4171)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getType(UnitCompiler.java:6393)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getType2(UnitCompiler.java:6780)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$14300(UnitCompiler.java:218)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$2$1.visitAmbiguousName(UnitCompiler.java:6421)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$2$1.visitAmbiguousName(UnitCompiler.java:6418)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$AmbiguousName.accept(Java.java:4279)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$2.visitLvalue(UnitCompiler.java:6418)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$2.visitLvalue(UnitCompiler.java:6414)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Lvalue.accept(Java.java:4203)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22.visitRvalue(UnitCompiler.java:6414)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22.visitRvalue(UnitCompiler.java:6393)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Rvalue.accept(Java.java:4171)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getType(UnitCompiler.java:6393)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.findIMethod(UnitCompiler.java:8960)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet2(UnitCompiler.java:4988)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$9100(UnitCompiler.java:218)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$16.visitMethodInvocation(UnitCompiler.java:4452)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$16.visitMethodInvocation(UnitCompiler.java:4425)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$MethodInvocation.accept(Java.java:5128)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet(UnitCompiler.java:4425)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGetValue(UnitCompiler.java:5589)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:3810)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$5900(UnitCompiler.java:218)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$13.visitMethodInvocation(UnitCompiler.java:3788)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$13.visitMethodInvocation(UnitCompiler.java:3760)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$MethodInvocation.accept(Java.java:5128)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:3760)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:2363)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$1800(UnitCompiler.java:218)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$6.visitExpressionStatement(UnitCompiler.java:1497)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$6.visitExpressionStatement(UnitCompiler.java:1490)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$ExpressionStatement.accept(Java.java:2929)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:1490)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileStatements(UnitCompiler.java:1570)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:3398)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileDeclaredMethods(UnitCompiler.java:1360)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileDeclaredMethods(UnitCompiler.java:1333)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:825)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:435)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$400(UnitCompiler.java:218)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitPackageMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:414)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitPackageMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:409)
at org.codehaus.janino.Java$PackageMemberClassDeclaration.accept(Java.java:1417)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:409)
at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileUnit(UnitCompiler.java:381)
at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:237)
at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.compileToClassLoader(SimpleCompiler.java:466)
at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:216)
at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:207)
at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:80)
at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:75)
at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.Compiler$class.compile(Compiler.scala:33)
... 9 more
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? I see no SQL there.

Comment: udf is used in sql

Comment: Can you show us the SQL that you're having problems with.

Comment: The recommended way to tackle this kind of issue is to put all your user defined code in one `uber` jar that you give to the job manager when you submit your job. See this: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#avoiding-dynamic-classloading